# How Can I Write to response headers with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm just trying out Spring boot, and with that I have simple test JSP-page I'd like to convert to thymeleaf. The JSP has a top page directive that sets a response header. How Can I do the same thing in thymeleaf?

```
Index.jsp

    <%
        response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self');
    %>
```

Comment: Don't do it in THymeleaf, do it in your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't. Not in Thymeleaf. Set the response header in the Spring MVC controller.

Comment: Yes, I kind of knew this was really old style and bad coding, but I needed something quick and dirty just for testing CSP posting from a page and didn't know where to start with thymeleaf  - anyway thanks for the tutorial, I'll read up on it a bit more.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be judgemental. I've just JSPs turned into awfulness. One page, 1,000's of lines of code long. OO principles tossed out the window....

I have a bunch of content on my site around Thymeleaf. Good luck getting started. Its pretty cool stuff!